# Make an object's dimensions oscillate in size using canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm playing around with canvas and I want to make a square which when clicked gets an initial burst of energy (for lack of a better word) which causes it to grow and shrink on both the X and Y axis, this energy will degrade over time until the animation stops.

I can do the Javascript bit but what I need is a function which can calculate the multiplier I use to scale the objects dimensions.

So ideally here is the pseudo-code I would use:

```
var scale = 1, previousScale = 1;

function draw() {
    previousScale = scale;
    scale = recalculateScale(); // I can't write this magic function

    var x = x * scale
      , y = y * scale;

    // draw code here

    // if the scale hasn't changed since last redraw then we're done
    if (scale === previousScale) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw());
    }
}

draw();
```

If you could also tell me the names of the methods you are using to calculate this value I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: You might be interested in Math.sin: 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the article, I know it's something to do with sin waves but I don't really know how they work so this article will be useful. The bigger problem for me is how to simulate the degrading energy as there isn't a whole lot of information on that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var now_value = new Number(); //this is a global var. 


function recalculateScale(indice) {

if (!indice) var index = 0;
else {var index = indice;}

var limit = (3/2)*(3.14); //this is when sin function is starting growing again (more or less when index is 3.14+1.57, so after it has been decreasing for some time, and i think this is where you should stop. But you are free to choose according to easing you 

scale = Math.sin(index);

now_value = scale;
console.log(now_value)

if (index < limit) {
setTimeout(function() {
recalculateScale(index+0.1) //you can change 0.1 to any value you want, according to how much linear you want your animation to be
}, 20) //you can change 20 to any values, these are milliseconds
}
else {console.log('animation finished'); now_value = 0;}

}
```

Just call function recalculateScale() when you want your animation to start, then each time you need the value of scale just get var now_value, which is global and it is modifying during the transition. when the transition finishes, it will come to his original value, 0.

Please note that with this example the values of now_value will value from 0 to 1 in 1/3 of time, then from 1 to - 1 in 2/3 of time.

Could't test it, i hope it'll work or help.

-edit-- 
yes it works, these are explained output:

```
0.09983341664682802 VM571:15
0.19866933079506113 VM571:15
0.29552020666133944 VM571:15
0.38941834230864997 VM571:15
0.47942553860420295 VM571:15
0.5646424733950346 VM571:15
0.6442176872376908 VM571:15
0.7173560908995221 VM571:15
0.7833269096274824 VM571:15
0.8414709848078963 VM571:15
0.8912073600614339 VM571:15
0.9320390859672261 VM571:15
0.9635581854171918 VM571:15
0.9854497299884593 VM571:15
0.9974949866040542 VM571:15
0.9995736030415037 VM571:15
0.9916648104524685 VM571:15
0.9738476308781938 VM571:15
0.9463000876874136 VM571:15
0.909297426825681 VM571:15
0.8632093666488722 VM571:15
0.8084964038195898 VM571:15
0.7457052121767187 VM571:15
0.67546318055115 VM571:15
0.5984721441039556 VM571:15
0.5155013718214626 VM571:15
0.4273798802338289 VM571:15
0.3349881501559032 VM571:15
0.23924932921398087 VM571:15
0.14112000805986563 VM571:15
0.04158066243328894 VM571:15
-0.05837414342758142 VM571:15
-0.15774569414324974 VM571:15
-0.2555411020268329 VM571:15
-0.35078322768962117 VM571:15
-0.4425204432948536 VM571:15
-0.5298361409084947 VM571:15
-0.6118578909427198 VM571:15
-0.6877661591839753 VM571:15
-0.7568024953079285 VM571:15
-0.8182771110644106 VM571:15
-0.8715757724135881 VM571:15
-0.916165936749454 VM571:15
-0.9516020738895161 VM571:15
-0.9775301176650958 VM571:15
-0.9936910036334636 VM571:15
-0.9999232575641003 VM571:15
-0.9961646088358395
```

The first call is index = 0.1, so output value is 0.09983341664682802 (sin(0) = 0). When index is around pi/2 (1.57 more or less), sin function values 1, and then starts decreasing to - 1, when index value will be 3/2*pi. total time is: (limit you put / the interval you choose) * milliseconds, in our case (((3/2)*pi)/(0.1))*20.

it's enough you look at the graph of the sin function to understand how index and now_value are related.

pi is 3.14.

Comment: add +1 to now_value when you use it and it'll start from 1 (which is the start position), it will grow to 2, which is the maximum size of your explosion, and it will grow down to 0, which is the end.

remember 1 is neutral in * operations

Answer (score 1):

**You can combine requestAnimationFrame plus easing to accomplish your sizing oscillations.**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/g48LR/

An `easing` will change a value (like your scale factor) over a time duraton.

Here's an example of an easing function that will oscillate the value during the cycle of the easing:

The values sent to the easing are:

- t == the elapsed time since the start of the easing,
- b == the beginning value (for example, the scaling will begin at 1.00)
- c == the amount that the beginning value will change over the course of the easing (for example, the scaling will increase by .25)
- d == the time duration for the easing

A function to ease with oscillation:

```
function easeOutBounce(t, b, c, d){
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
}
```

Here is a great explanation of how requestAnimationFrame+easing work together:

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_easing_functions_in_javascript.htm

And here is the code for the Demo above:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var startTime
    var duration=1000;  // animate over 1000ms
    var totChange=.25;  // change the size by 25%

    var cx=150;
    var cy=150;
    var iw,ih;
    var img=new Image();
    img.isLoaded=false;
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="house100x100.png";
    function start(){
        iw=img.width;
        ih=img.height;
        this.isLoaded=true;
    }

    function animate(time){

        if(time<=endTime){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

        var elapsed=time-startTime;

        var value=easeOutBounce(elapsed,1.00,totChange,duration);

        var w=iw*value;
        var h=ih*value;
        var x=cx-w/2;
        var y=cy-h/2;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iw,ih,x,y,w,h);

    }

    function easeOutBounce(t, b, c, d){
        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
          return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
        } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
          return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
        } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
          return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
        } else {
          return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
        }
    }

    $("#test").click(function(){
        if(img.isLoaded){
            startTime=lastTime=performance.now();
            endTime=startTime+duration;
            animate(startTime);
        }
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">Test</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```